# Why does the little help box call them "backticks" when they're graves?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I've noticed that when the little help box appears to the side, it says to show code using "backticks" when they are called graves.  For clarification, I am talking about these: `.  I don't think that these should be called backticks.

Comment: All of these are names for the accent grave: acute, backtick, grave, grave accent, left quote, open quote, push, backquote, back prime, backtick, birk, blugle, quasiquote, and unapostrophe.

Comment: "*Why is it called 'full stop' when it's 'period'*?"

Answer (score 9):

Both names, "grave (accent)" and "backtick" apply to the same character.

"grave" is more common in the linguistic field and when it's actually combined with a letter (like "è").

"backtick" is the name commonly used in technical or programming contexts, where it is used on its own like a quotation mark instead. Just like here in the Markdown editor, where you enclose text with `backticks` to `format it as code`.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming